# Using mutt and not revealing IP address

Tags: email, mutt

Here is `mutt` setup: I use `offlineimap` to fetch the mail and use `msmtp` to send the mail.

My concern is that when using this (`msmtp`), it appends my IP address in the header in every email that is sent. Since `msmtp` doesn't support a `SOCKS` proxy, I can't use a SSH tunnel to my VPS.

Is there anyway I can configure this setup to not reveal my IP address by using some sort of a tunnel to my VPS so that its IP is revealed and not mine? I searched a lot but the closest I could find was a SSH tunnel but I guess that was for the case if I was using `mutt`'s inbuilt `SMTP` support and not a MTA such as `msmtp`.

Comment: Can you include an example of the IP in the header just so everyone knows exactly what you have and what you're trying to remove?

Comment: @slm I have a similar problem, it looks like this: ``Received: from macos.local ([WW.XXX.YY.ZZ])`` which is my external IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap `msmtp` in `tsocks` or `socksify` (from `dante-client`) to make msmtp use your SOCKS server.